# How to center image contained in ImageView after a modify on it?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view

I've written a little piece of code, Thanks to stackoverflows users, where I fill with some color different regions of an image using the "Flood fill" algorithm. The problem is that the result of this modify isn't placed in the center of the screen. See below:

[image: green sheep]

I suppose that this happens because I don't set the View's paramnetres correctly, as you can see in the code below:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class Main extends Activity {

 // private RelativeLayout drawingLayout;
    private MyView myView;
 // public ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     //     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     //     this.drawingLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawingLayout);

     //     image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.immagine);

            this.myView = new MyView(Main.this);
            setContentView(myView);
    //      this.drawingLayout.addView(myView);
 }

public class MyView extends View {

     private Paint paint;
    private Path path;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    final Point p1 = new Point();
    Canvas canvas;

     //Bitmap mutableBitmap ;
     public MyView(Context context) {

         super(context);

         this.paint = new Paint();
         this.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
         pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
         this.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.leone).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
         this.path = new Path();
     }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            p1.x = (int) x;
            p1.y = (int) y;
            final int sourceColor = mBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
            final int targetColor = paint.getColor();
            new TheTask(mBitmap, p1, sourceColor, targetColor).execute();
            invalidate();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getCurrentPaintColor() {
        return paint.getColor();
    }

    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        Bitmap bmp;
        Point pt;
        int replacementColor, targetColor;

        public TheTask(Bitmap bm, Point p, int sc, int tc) {
            this.bmp = bm;
            this.pt = p;
            this.replacementColor = tc;
            this.targetColor = sc;
            pd.setMessage("Filling....");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            FloodFill f = new FloodFill();
            f.floodFill(bmp, pt, targetColor, replacementColor);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

// flood fill
public class FloodFill {

    public void floodFill(Bitmap image, Point node, int targetColor, int replacementColor) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int target = targetColor;
        int replacement = replacementColor;
        if (target != replacement) {
            Queue<Point> queue = new LinkedList<Point>();
            do {

                int x = node.x;
                int y = node.y;
                while (x > 0 && image.getPixel(x - 1, y) == target) {
                    x--;

                }
                boolean spanUp = false;
                boolean spanDown = false;
                while (x < width && image.getPixel(x, y) == target) {
                    image.setPixel(x, y, replacement);
                    if (!spanUp && y > 0
                            && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y - 1));
                        spanUp = true;
                    } else if (spanUp && y > 0
                            && image.getPixel(x, y - 1) != target) {
                        spanUp = false;
                    }
                    if (!spanDown && y < height - 1
                            && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) == target) {
                        queue.add(new Point(x, y + 1));
                        spanDown = true;
                    } else if (spanDown && y < height - 1
                            && image.getPixel(x, y + 1) != target) {
                        spanDown = false;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            } while ((node = queue.poll()) != null);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Is that possible to set the ImageView as editable, so that I can color it with Flood Fill algorithm, instead of the Main's View?

Can you tell me how to set this image to center of the screen and resize it properly?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Math

You need to get screen dimensions using the following and adjust the onTouchEvent method if I'm not wrong to account for different dimensions.

If you want the the display dimensions in pixels you can use [`getSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you're not in an `Activity` you can get the default `Display` via `WINDOW_SERVICE`:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Before `getSize` was introduced (in API level 13), you could use the `getWidth` and `getHeight` methods that are now deprecated:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

## 2. Scaletype.

Extend an `ImageView` and use this attribute.

if `imgView` is the image view you want to center. Then do:

```
imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
```

Comment: ImageView is what I want to center, but I don't know how to add it to the view "myView" which I build in "onCreate" method, and I modify then! Can you tell me how to do this?!

Comment: `myView` is extending `View` which does not have the ScaleType attribute,let me update the answer to suit this.

Comment: Ok i checked it, but if I want to extend the image to all the screen portion dedicated to the modifies what can I do?

Comment: check the `math` portion of the answer on how to scale